# docker run with port-forward fails

Tags: java, docker

This is my docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim

RUN mkdir /app

COPY dept-1.0.jar /app

CMD java -jar /app/dept-1.0.jar

EXPOSE 8080
```

The docker image can be run without any issues if I were to run like without port-forward
`docker run --name=department dept:latest`

But with port-forward `docker run --name=department dept:latest -p 8082:8080` I see this error -

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"-p\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

Can someone help pls ?

Comment: Put the `-p` option before the image name `dept:latest`.  (After, Docker interprets it as the command to run.)

Comment: see [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

Comment: This solved my issue. Changed ```CMD java -jar /app/dept-1.0.jar``` to ```ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/dept-1.0.jar"]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the following in the Dockerfil

`CMD java -jar /app/dept-1.0.jar`

to

`ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/dept-1.0.jar"]`

This solved my issue.